# How to use dataSource and delegate methods with RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm trying to use UIPickerView with RxSwift. Is there a way to wrap the UIPickerView dataSource and delegate methods to be used with Observables? I'm trying to do something like

```
dataSequence
    .bindTo(pickerView.rx_itemsWithDataSource(dataSource))
```

I see there is a premade library for UITableview 
https://github.com/RxSwiftCommunity/RxDataSources but I'm wondering if there's an easy way to generalize this for other things that require dataSource and delegate using RxSwift.

Comment: RxCocoa already has a UIPickerView extension. Maybe you can just use that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic RxCocoa pod which you should have imported with RxSwift in the podfile should already had this.

In case you didn't import that in your podfile, add

```
pod 'RxCocoa',    '~> 3.0'
```

Proceed then to bind the delegate like you would with a normal TableView. I didn't see any dataSource observable for UIPickerView though, so you should check that.

Comment: This functionality has been added to the core library